# Format a date after putting it in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using a DatePicker to let someone pick a certain week.

The html is basically like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="beginDate" />
    <input type="text" id="endDate" />
</form>
```

And the javascript is this now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#beginDate").datepicker(
        { dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            onSelect: function () {
                var mon = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                mon.setDate(mon.getDate() + 1 - (mon.getDay() || 7));
                var sun = new Date(mon.getTime());
                sun.setDate(sun.getDate() + 6);
                $(this).val(mon);
                $('#endDate').val(sun);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

That works, kind of... It puts `Mon Nov 21 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100` and `Sun Nov 27 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100` in my textboxes.

I want them to be in a "dd-mm-yyyy" format, so just `21/11/2011`. 
I tried things such as `.formatDate`, but that does not seem to work.

I know I could do something like `mon.GetDay() + "/" +  mon.GetMonth() + "/" etc` but javascript must have some kind of proper date formatter, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no date format function in JavaScript itself, but you are using jQuery ui so try this:

```
$('#endDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', sun));
```

Answer (score 0):

> javascript must have some kind of proper date formatter, right?

You'd think wouldn't you, but no. The solution in your OP is the best to use, ie. concatenating the date together in a string, but don't forget to add 1 to `mon.GetMonth()` as it's zero based:

```
var dateString = mon.GetDay() + "/" + (mon.GetMonth() + 1) + "/" + mon.getFullYear();
```

There is a nice script you can use which provides the usual gamut of date formatting functions which other languages provide [**here**](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)